# How to have the value of "Access mask"?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl, ntfs

I would like to have the value of "access mask" and not in text:
If I did:

```
Get-Acl .\MyFolder | % {$_.Access}

FileSystemRights  : WriteAttributes, ReadAndExecute, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : EU\Test
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
```

The value of `FileSystemRights` is a text, and I would like a number.
The "access mask" is: [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374896.aspx)

Do you know a means to have the value of the "access mask"?

Comment: The numeric value of the access permissions can be obtained via `.FileSystemRights.value__`.

Comment: I find this [link](https://github.com/terrytrent/GetAccessMask_WPF), So now it's ok